How to analyze the driver of a flipped sign regression result?
I have a panel dataset uniquely identified by $i$ and $t$. I am interested in the relationship between $x$ and $y$ and I want to an OLS regression with unit fixed effects ($\phi_i$) as follows:
$$y_{it}=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{it} + \phi_i + \epsilon_{it}$$
The true $y$ is perfectly observable. The true $x$ is not empirically observable but can be proxied by two alternative variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are highly correlated, with a correlation coefficient around 0.85.
However, when I run the above OLS regression by replacing $x$ with $x_1$ and $x_2$ separately, the sign of $\beta_1$ is different, one positive and one negative. I am surprised because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are highly correlated. How can I better understand the reason(s) behind the sign flip?
